# Wordpress not inserting subdirectory name into address bar

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've installed Wordpress into a subdirectory on a localhost (testing)

localhost/website/media/ ('media' being the Wordpress subdirectory (obvs))

The remaining areas outside of the Wordpress instal are static HTML files.

Now.. Everything appeared to be running fine, until I discovered that both the 'Wordpress Address URL' and 'Site Address URL' both showed:

```
localhost/website/media/
```

Aware of this I then changed the Site Address URL to 
    http://localhost/website

However, Whenever I now view posts I'm getting the following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /website/index.php was not found on this server.
```

It seems as though wordpress is missing out the 'media' subdirectory folder which is bizarre given I haven't changed the 'Wordpress Address URL'.

Why change  it in the first place, if it was originally working so well (I hear you ask?)

2 reasons -

First, mild case of OCD,

Secondly, I've created a child theme and inserted the following code which relies heavily on the 'Site Address URL' being correct:

```
<img class="footer-social-logo" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>/img/social/facebook-col.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="Facebook Logo">
```

I've scoured the web and I can't find anything that points to what the issue may be. My last hope is you guys..

Cheers,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Try out to set correct URL in settings if wp-admin->settings>general in case it is reachable. Then rewrite .htaccess file and wp-config as well because they all contain old pathes. Then if it will not be helpfull download database and rewrite pathes there too. Hope it helps.

Comment: I’ll give that a go, thanks. .htaccess is beyond my level of understanding (as a newbie) so I’ll do some digging on Google, see what’s required!